# Is the latency period of Ubuntu zero for use of Aud 1 App ? I have hearing problem

Tags: volume-control

Is the latency period of Ubuntu zero for use of Aud 1 App ? I have hearing problem. Is there any other app that will assist me in hearing with range of 80 - 100 dB.